# Error opening Tomcat Page at port 8080

Tags: tomcat, liferay

I managed to copy the entire Liferay+Tomcat 7 bundle onto a server.

When I run the startup.sh file, Tomcat produces the following results in `catalina.out`:

```
Jul 25, 2013 12:22:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /data/java/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server:/data/java/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64:/data/java/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 25, 2013 12:22:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 25, 2013 12:22:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 25, 2013 12:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1965 ms
Jul 25, 2013 12:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 25, 2013 12:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Jul 25, 2013 12:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/henry/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
Jul 25, 2013 12:23:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/henry/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/welcome-theme
Jul 25, 2013 12:23:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/henry/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/resources-importer-web
Jul 25, 2013 12:23:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/henry/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/marketplace-portlet
Jul 25, 2013 12:23:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 25, 2013 12:23:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 25, 2013 12:23:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 67754 ms
```

But, when I try to enter `ipaddress_of_server:8080`, they said site not found.

I ran a lsof on my server

```
[henry@batik1 ~]$ lsof -i:8080
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    6643 henry   52u  IPv6 184032      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
java    6643 henry  277u  IPv6 184072      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:47100->localhost.local
```

Does anyone know how do I access the page?

Comment: You have only displayed the tomcat stderr log.  In order to see what Liferay Portal did during startup you need to display the stdout output, which may not be available on the console.  Try going to <liferay.home>/logs/liferay.xxx.log and see what you find there.

Comment: Try running `netstat`. I find the output more clear than `lsof`. Tomcat is showing no errors, so your server should be running. Is it possible that you have not bound your HTTP connector to the right IP address? By default, Tomcat listens to `0.0.0.0` (i.e. all interfaces), but you can force it to listen on a specific interface if you want to. What do you get if you try to `telnet ipaddress_of_server 8080`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Liferay started up normally (but add more information - catalina.out or others, as gamerson requested in a comment)

Also:

- Check Firewall settings (8080 might be blocked)
- Your `lsof` output lists IPV6 (it's been long since I interpreted lsof output and commandline - this might be normal, or not. You don't say if you attempt an IPV4 connection)
- Try to connect with a browser from that server. If it's a shell-only server, use `w3m` or `lynx` on `http://localhost:8080/`